# I have a question about communication (for example, CAN, LIN, MOST, etc.); where should I ask it?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I often have questions about the theory behind the communication protocols used (mostly in vehicles), but I could not find a Stack Exchange site that fits the most. Since it is not a programming question it does not belong on Stack Overflow, but not really a electrical engineering question either.

The question I have was posted by me on SO [LIN-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989851/can-the-two-paritiy-bits-in-the-lin-datatelegram-guarantee-that-every-error-is-c) and asks about the security layer, and the parity check sum polynomials in particular. It does not provide a programming code, cause the question is if there is a theory or something that provides an easier solution.

Comment: a quick [search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=can+lin+most) reveals a single question on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25561/difference-between-obdii-and-can  and one on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219184/can-network-to-lin-network-gateway-possible but to make the final call we need a bit more content of the actual question you want to ask.

Comment: Your question on SO seems to be a programming problem but lacks an attempt / shows what already tried with Python (or Matlab for that matter) so by SO standards I doubt it is a great question. Looks like you want us to do the work for you.

Comment: The question is more if there is an easier way to do it without having to program it, like a rule sth etc. that I am not aware of. The programing part would be the last resort

Comment: The current wording of the question sounds quite broad, but I think the problem itself could work in the [tag:algorithm] tag (probably without languages: pseudocode answers can be converted to your language of choice perhaps). I'd look around in that tag to see what kind of questions are well-received nowadays. (cc @rene)

Comment: Algorithm tag of SO of course; I didn't realize this was MSE...

Comment: I cannot speak for either community, so read their help pages and look through possibly related questions, but from the looks of your main question, it _might_ be a fit for [cs.se] or possibly [cstheory.se]. The former seems more likely as the latter seems to be more "professional" based. Ignore the language, and just look toward finding a "proof" that all bits are, or are not, protected by the given scheme.